# Erro de InflateException

Tags: java, android

Estou recebendo um erro de `InflateException`, porem não sei como resolver.

Erro:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
>   Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                                                      at
>   br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:23)

Linha de erro:

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Classe:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        LatLng marker = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 13));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Hello Google Maps!").position(marker));
```

XML:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.MainActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Quais são os outros xml do projeto? Verifique se existe algum erro em qualquer um deles.

Comment: Não tem erro em nenhum xml.

Comment: Isso geralmente é erro em XML mesmo.

Comment: @LariSouza você está conseguindo importar a classe R?

Comment: Estou sim @CaiqueOliveira.

Comment: É só esse *xml* que tem? Julgo que não deverá ser esse que deve usar no *inflate*.